# Detected height of a percentage-width-div is still the same after resizing the window? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is hard to explain… so I opened a Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qga046f3/

Goal: My goal is to get three divs of the same height. So I detect all the heights and choose the biggest one and apply this height to the other div-containers. 
If the user resizes the browser-window the heights of the divs should be re-adjust. But jQuery gives me always the same height from first time. Why?

This is my jQuery code:

```
var adjustheights = function(){
    heights = [];
    $('.element').each(function(i){
        heights.push($(this).outerHeight());
    }); 
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
    $('.element').css('height', maxHeight);
    $('.maxheight').html(maxHeight);
}

adjustheights();

$(window).resize(function(){
    adjustheights();    
});
```

Comment: because their height isrelative to the hight of the parent element and not the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset (remove) the height of each element before adding the new one. jQuery adds an inline style when you set a height via CSS, so you need to remove it and add it again with the new value: (http://jsfiddle.net/qga046f3/4/)

```
var adjustheights = function(){

        heights = [];

        $('.element').each(function(i){
            // Reset height first
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            heights.push($(this).outerHeight());
        }); 

        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

        $('.element').css('height', maxHeight);

        $('.maxheight').html(maxHeight);

        console.log(heights);
}

adjustheights();

$(window).resize(function(){

        adjustheights();

});
```